# 404 returned when trying to fetch ID token from inside docker container in cloud build

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, google-auth-library-nodejs

I have a NextJs app that uses an API hosted on Google Cloud Run during its static site generation (SSG). The SSG happens during the build step, which is performed inside a docker node.js container in Cloud Build. However, I get this error during the build:

```
Step #0: Error: Could not fetch ID token: Unsuccessful response status code. Request failed with status code 404
Step #0:     at Gaxios._request (/app/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:129:23)
Step #0:     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Step #0:     at async metadataAccessor (/app/node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js:68:21)
Step #0:     at async Compute.fetchIdToken (/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/computeclient.js:80:23)
Step #0:     at async IdTokenClient.getRequestMetadataAsync (/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/idtokenclient.js:35:29)
Step #0:     at async IdTokenClient.getRequestHeaders (/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:247:26)
...
```

This happens when trying to fetch an ID token with the `google-auth-library` like so:

```
await this.googleAuth.getIdTokenClient(...)
```

The build command running the build (the `-t` parameter is passed the image name and version, I just omitted it here):

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '--network=cloudbuild', '-t', '...', '.']
```

The 404 error indicates that Cloud Build can't find whatever service is used to get an ID token. I have found some similar errors:

- [Google Cloud Build fetch Identity token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252736/google-cloud-build-fetch-identity-token) -> This workaround would be a bit of a hassle to implement for us. I'm hoping to avoid it.

Is there any way to allow `google-auth-library` to fetch an ID token inside Cloud Build?

Comment: If Google allowed you to fetch an Identity Token from the Cloud Build service, you would be able to impersonate Cloud Build. That would be a security issue. You will need to create your own Identity Token from one of your service accounts.

Comment: @JohnHanley Is that what is described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64268716/11297850? Or is there some other docs you know of that could help me get started? I'm kind of new to GCP :)

Comment: Yes, that answer shows you how to solve your problem. The first method is easy to implement as Cloud Build provides a builder for the CLI.

Comment: @JohnHanley 1. How safe is it to print the access token into the terminal with `gcloud auth print-access-token`? 2. I would then need to pass the id token to the `google-auth-library` manually as a parameter?

Comment: The risk is something showing up in the Cloud Build logs. Do not print to the terminal, capture the output in a variable.

Comment: @JohnHanley Is there a more complete example of how to do this somewhere? Ideally step-by-step.

Comment: Your link has what you need to do. I am not aware of a more in-depth step-by-step article. Creating a Cloud Build step with the CLI is easy. Read the docs and practice.

Comment: @ptf as John Hanley mentioned you can go though the Stackoverflow URL:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252736/google-cloud-build-fetch-identity-token/64268716#64268716  and you can refer documents https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest & https://medium.com/google-cloud/service-account-credentials-api-a-solution-to-different-issues-dc7434037115